# How to count active users when given account creation and deletion timestamps

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have rows containing user information, including two timestamp values contains 'created' and 'deleted' data (where 'deleted' is null if the account is active), is there a way to count active users on a given day (i.e. between those two values)?

Example:

| id | created | deleted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2022-05-01 | 2022-08-01 |
| 02 | 2022-06-01 | 2022-08-13 |
| 03 | 2022-07-01 | NULL |

What I would like returned:

| date | active_user_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 1 |
| 2022-06-01 | 2 |
| 2022-07-01 | 3 |
| 2022-08-01 | 2 |
| 2022-08-25 | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is to count *created* as +1 and *deleted* as -1.
In your data sample each date appears only once, but in a real life scenario we can expect multiple entries (created/deleted) in a single day. Therefore, we first need to calculate the daily sum of the entries and then calculate a running total.

```
select  dt
       ,sum(sum(delta)) over(order by dt) as active_user_count
from 
(         select id, created as dt,  1 as delta from t
union all select id, deleted,       -1          from t where deleted is not null
) t
group by dt
```

| dt | active_user_count |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 2022-06-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2022-07-01 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
| 2022-08-13 00:00:00 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf53248bda90ade51967eb979bcc56c3&hide=1)

Comment: MySql and BigQuery are two different things please tag the relevant db/sql-engine.